# Variable out of scope (probably) - undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

So this piece of code is returning description of word in json from https://sjp.pl/ webiste, word which user provied before in request json body

And problem is that i want to send back var 'desc' in res.send but its undefined. How I can access that and send it?

I think thats because item.push($(this).text()) is working only in this axios function and can be accessed only in this scope

```
const item = [];
var desc;

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    const { word } = req.body;

    if(!word) {
        res.status(418).send({error: 'no word provided'})
    }

    console.log(word)

    axios(`https://sjp.pl/${word}`).then(res => {

        const html = res.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)

        $('p').each(function() {
            item.push($(this).text())
        })

        desc = item[3]

        console.log(desc) // working until here
    })

    console.log(desc) // undefined here

    res.send({
        description: `${desc}`
    })
})
```

Comment: The axios request is processed asynchronously. That means that the code execution goes straight to res.send after the axios call is triggered but before it's completed. Simply put your res.send call inside then handler (after desc = items[3]).

Comment: I have tried put res.send after this dec = items[3] but I am getting error from Insomnia: "Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer"

Comment: Other than that I am getting exception from console: "TypeError: res.send is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `res` inside the `axios` like below. You are getting `undefined` because the `desc` scope ends inside that anonymous function. Moreover the `axios` is `async`. You may need to use `await` to make it `sync` or can follow the idea I proposed below.

```
const item = [];
var desc;

app.post('/test', (req, res0) => {
    const { word } = req.body;

    if(!word) {
        res0.status(418).send({error: 'no word provided'})
    }

    console.log(word)

    axios(`https://sjp.pl/${word}`).then(res => {

        const html = res.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)

        $('p').each(function() {
            item.push($(this).text())
        })

        desc = item[3]

        res0.send({
            description: `${desc}`
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: I was trying to do this, but its not working, output from Insomnia: Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer

Comment: Are you able to send a testing response to the client? I mean some response other than provided by axios?

Comment: When I moved res.send into the axios function, theres a exepcion: "TypeError: res.send is not a function"

Comment: That makes sense because `res` of outside and inside `axios` has same name. So, `res` variable inside `axios` shadowed it. Try giving a different name and share the behavior.

Comment: I have changed the variable name for you. Do try with the edited code above.

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you very much, yes I see this now